# Add Layers to Arcmap 10 Crashes

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, c#

Would anyone know the reason why this happens? and possibly a way to fix it. I am stumped

In the following code. The first addlayer works, but crashes on the second addlayer with a 'vshost32.exe has stopped working' error.

However when I comment out all the addlayers and make it to the for loop.  All three addlayers display correctly.

Why would the exact same code work in a for loop, but not when add a second, third and fourth layer individually.

Any ideas?

---

I have taken care of the error, however when I stop the program, I loose the data in Arcmap 10

```
// want to open shapefile
pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("wa_body_" + sGeoname);
pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");

pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
pDataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)pFeatureClass;
pFeatureLayer.Name = pDataset.Name;

pMap.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(QCForm.chkLstNSHNPolygons.Items[8].ToString()); // "wa_poly_" + sGeoname);
pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
pDataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)pFeatureClass;
pFeatureLayer.Name = pDataset.Name;

pMap.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(QCForm.chkLstNSHNLines.Items[4].ToString());// "nshn_line_" + sGeoname);
pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
pDataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)pFeatureClass;
pFeatureLayer.Name = pDataset.Name;

pMap.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(QCForm.chkLstNSHNPoints.Items[5].ToString()); // "nshn_point_" + sGeoname);
pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
pDataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)pFeatureClass;
pFeatureLayer.Name = pDataset.Name;

pMap.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(QCForm.chkLstNSHNJunctions.Items[4].ToString()); // "nshn_junc_" + sGeoname);
pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
 pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
 pDataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)pFeatureClass;
 pFeatureLayer.Name = pDataset.Name;

 pMap.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

 //Add topology layers
 i = 0;

 for (i = 0; i <= lstFeatures.Items.Count - 1; i++)
 {
     pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(lstFeatures.Items[i].ToString());
     pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
     pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
     pDataset = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IDataset)pFeatureClass;
     pFeatureLayer.Name = pDataset.Name;

     pMap.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);
 }
```

}

Comment: What is pObjectFactory set to?

Comment: pObjectFactory = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IObjectFactory)m_pApplication;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working:

```
private void btnViewInArcMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pLocalWorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();

    string sGeoname = null;

    pObjectFactory = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IObjectFactory)m_pApplication;

    IBasicDocument document = (IBasicDocument)m_pApplication.Document;

    pMxDocument = (ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument)m_Document;
    pMap = pMxDocument.FocusMap;

    switch (clsGlobal.ConnectType)
    {
        case clsGlobal.ConnectionTypeEnum.SHP:
            //Use reflection to get ClsID of ShapefileWorkspaceFactory.
            Type shpWkspFactType = typeof(ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass);

            string typeClsID = shpWkspFactType.GUID.ToString("B");

            pLocalWorkspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)pObjectFactory.Create(typeClsID);
            break;
    }

    pLocalFeatureWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)pLocalWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(clsGlobal.pWorkspace.PathName, 0);

    // want to open shapefile
    pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("wa_body_" + sGeoname);
    // Create the layer
    pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
    pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
    pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

    document.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

    pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("wa_poly_" + sGeoname);
    // Create the layer
    pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
    pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
    pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

    document.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

    pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("nshn_line_" + sGeoname);
    // Create the layer
    pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
    pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
    pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

    document.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

    pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("nshn_point_" + sGeoname);
    // Create the layer
    pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
    pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
    pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

    document.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

    pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("nshn_junc_" + sGeoname);
    // Create the layer
    pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
    pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
    pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

    document.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);

    //Add topology layers
    i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= lstFeatures.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        pFeatureClass = pLocalFeatureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(lstFeatures.Items[i].ToString());
        // Create the layer
        pFeatureLayer = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer)pObjectFactory.Create("esriCarto.FeatureLayer");
        pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass = pFeatureClass;
        pFeatureLayer.Name = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.AliasName;

        document.AddLayer(pFeatureLayer);
    }
}
```